# What is this small space-themed set from possibly the early 90's?

Tags: set-identification

I have a bunch of LEGO bricks mixed together.  I recognize a few of them as going together for some small set that I no longer have the instructions for.  I believe I got this set in the early 90's.  The minifigure rode some sort of small contraption.  What set is this?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is most probably [Ice Planet Scooter](https://brickset.com/sets/1711-1/Ice-Planet-Scooter):

[image: Ice Planet Scooter]

Answer (score 5):

Ice Planet - Looks like Star Wars before Legos marketed for Star Wars.
https://lego.brickinstructions.com/en/lego_instructions/set/1711/Ice_Planet_Scooter

Comment: The link does not seem to bring any more useful information.

Comment: @mindstormsboi It contains the building schematics and a picture of the rest of the result. It's a source. There's nothing wrong with the link.

Comment: Oh, I was paying attention to the orange box saying ther's  no instructions and yet there are instructions. Couldn't you have clarified that?

Comment: @mindstormsboi No, your point made sense, because the older answer from the day before seems to have more useful information in the link there. This answer doesn't seem to contribute much that the other answer didn't already have.